# Mysql SQL query to exclude specific records

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a `bills` table which has a foreign key `prior_bill_id`, which refers to a bill record. For each bill, there could be one or more `readings` with it, there's a joint table `bill_readings` for the association.

```
| bills         |
| --------------|
| id            |
| prior_bill_id |
```

```
| readings |
| -------- |
| id       |
```

```
| bill_reaadings |
| ---------------|
| bill_id        |
| reading_id     |
```

I am trying to come up with a SQL to find all the readings of a bill excluding readings of prior bill of the given bill, here's what I've come up with, would you please correct me if there's anything wrong with it? TIA

```
    WITH CTE_readings AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT br.bill_id, br.reading_id
        FROM bills
        INNER JOIN bill_readings br ON br.bill_id=bills.id
    ), CTE_prior_readings AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT bills.id bill_id, pbr.reading_id
        FROM bills
        INNER JOIN bill_readings pbr ON pbr.bill_id=bills.prior_bill_id
    ) SELECT r.bill_id, r.reading_id
        FROM CTE_readings r
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_prior_readings pr ON pr.reading_id=r.reading_id
        WHERE pr.bill_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: It will better and more clear if you provide table structure for this.

Comment: @sssurii done updating the original post

Comment: If foreign key has same table relation? can please also update the foreign key column to tables.

Comment: @sssurii ahh, sure, done

Comment: OP in your CTE_prior_readings you still select bills.id , is this what you intended or should it be bills.prior_bill_id

Comment: @T.Peter yes, that's intended

Comment: @leomayleomay just to confirm, if bills and readings has Many::Many relationship? OR One::Many relationship?

Comment: @sssurii one to many, while there's no FK on `readings`, the association is established by the joint table `bill_readings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the query I've come up with which works as expected

```
    WITH CTE_readings AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT br.bill_id, br.reading_id
        FROM bill_readings br
    ), CTE_prior_readings AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT bills.id bill_id, pbr.reading_id
        FROM bills
        INNER JOIN bill_readings pbr ON pbr.bill_id=bills.prior_billing_id
    ) SELECT r.bill_id, r.reading_id
        FROM CTE_readings r
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
            FROM CTE_prior_readings pr
            WHERE r.bill_id = pr.bill_id
              AND r.reading_id = pr.reading_id
        )
```

Comment: while the result is correct with above query, it's extremely slow for data set with 100k+ rows of `bill_readings`